# ffplay - adding subtitles on each vidio of hstack code

Tags: ffmpeg

-vf subtitles="Left.srt"
-vf subtitles="Rite.srt"

this part below works ok but how can this add Subtitles on each videos of hstack code?
I moved the code up above around the below command but no luck

FFPLAY.EXE -f lavfi "movie=Left.mkv:seek_point=174, setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];movie=Rite.mkv:seek_point=174, setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];[v0][v1]hstack"

thanx guys

Answer (score 0):

found it

Color White Subtitles

`FFPLAY.EXE" -f lavfi "movie=Left.mkv:seek_point=20.2,  scale=704:-1,subtitles=Left.SRT, setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];movie=Right.mkv:seek_point=6.2,scale=704:-1,subtitles=Right.srt, setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];[v0][v1]hstack"`

Yellow White Subtitles w/extra

`FFPLAY.EXE" -f lavfi "movie=Left.mkv:seek_point=20.2,  scale=704:-1,subtitles=.SRT:force_style='Fontsize=18,PrimaryColour=&H0000FFFF', setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];movie=Right.mkv:seek_point=6.2,scale=704:-1,subtitles=.srt:force_style='Fontsize=18,PrimaryColour=&H0000FFFF', setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];[v0][v1]hstack"`